# UWP remove "exit-full screen" in Control Box

Tags: c#, uwp, fullscreen

Is there a way to remove the "Exit-Fullscreen" button in UWP apps?

I know it is possible, as one app "4 pics 1 word" has done it. Below is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, there are only 2 buttons in the control box: Minimize and Close.

However, for other apps, there is another button that appears:

[image]

There are 3 buttons, Minimize, Close, and a new one, exit Full-Screen.

For resolution concerns, I would like my app to **always** be Full-Screen and not allow any option to exit full-screen. Alt-tab is okay.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no managed API to modify the control box of a `titlebar` in UWP apps other than the Fullscreen option you illustrated.

The reason the game you presented has a modified control box is because it's NOT a UWP application: if you check it's *System Requirements* in the Store it states that the minimum OS version is *Windows 8 or higher required*.

Comment: Thanks Matei, we did a work around to simulate what it was. Basically, we disabled edge-swipe using registry and added invisible bordes on the top and bottom that catches swipe events which then trigger the AppBars.

Comment: Sound like a valid solution, I like it!